# Diffing file contents

Tags: windows, diff

I have two plain text files, each file is containing a list of strings sorted alphabetically with one string per line. I want to diff the files and have an output of all strings that exist only in file2.

Preferabbly I want the operation to be possible without any 3rd party tools, or with a minimum of installations of tools that is "normal" to find in a windows command line environment, such as GNU Diffutils, Powershell, etc. The output should be in text form (file or as command line output).

Example:

```
File 1 contents:
A
C
D

File 2 contents:
A
B
C
E

Result wanted:
B
E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
comm -13 file_a file_b
```

*(`-13` is `-1` `-3`)*

---

```
diff a b | grep "^>"
```

```
diff a b | sed -n "/^>/ s/^> //p"
```

---

You can get a very minimal toolset from [UnxUtils](http://sf.net/projects/unxutils) -- outdated, yes, but enough for this one.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows PowerShell (direct port of [grawity's diff/grep combo](https://superuser.com/questions/151435/diffing-file-contents/151443#151443)):

```
Compare-Object (Get-Content file1) (Get-Content file2) |
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

This can be shortened to:

```
diff (gc file1) (gc file2) | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'} | %{$_.InputObject}
```

or wrapped in a function if you need it more often than once.

Comment: +1 Too bad I can't accept two answers. Works like a charm. Thanks!